# Firefox 3.6.24 putting gray border on some images

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

Firefox is putting a gray border on most of my images. The border is sometimes on the bottom or off to the right. If I add padding to the images sometimes the border will go away.

The images are not links and I have basically covered every option in CSS to eliminate the problem but have had no success:

```
body img{
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     -khtml-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

Hopefully someone has encountered this before or has some information to help?

Comment: What version of FF are you using?

Comment: Why are you using the shadow if it's not being applied.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Firefox?! We are now on Version 12. Also you might want to provide an example site or recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net, though I doubt there will be many people with that browser version to test.

Comment: can you reproduce on a page that contains nothing but the html,body and img tags?

Answer (score 0):

try adding an attribute to your html img tag like `border="0"`

Comment: are you sure you closed the img tags? FF 3.6 does not handle non-closed tags well. Make sure you use <img /> instead of <img>

Comment: @Steven Binder, I made those changes and added a closing tag.  Didn't work.